# Backup restore fails on multi-user mode error

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge, progress-db

I have a script to automate restoring a database from a backup. My script first stops all appserver instances, stops all databases, then restores from a backup. Below is the pseudo-code:

```
foreach appserver:
    asbman -name (appserver) -stop

foreach database:
    dbman -name (database) -stop

proutil database.db -C enablelargefiles
echo y | prorest database.db backup.bak -verbose
```

Once my script reaches the prorest command, it outputs the following error:

```
** The database D:\Directory\Wrk\db\database is in use in multi-user mode. (276)
```

After waiting ~60 seconds, running the prorest command again executes as expected, and the database is restored correctly. My guess is that there are processes tied to the database that are still running after the database is stopped. I would like to find a solution to this problem without having to use methods such as a sleep-retry to determine when the database is capable of being restored. Is there a solution to this problem, or are there better methods for restoring a database in this way?

Comment: Are you pausing at all after stopping the AppServers and database? They don't shut down instantaneously. You might have to do the sleep-retry method.

Comment: @TheDrooper I am currently not pausing after stopping the appservers/databases. Do you know why they don't shut down instantaneously? Or at least why dbman outputs that it has stopped?

Comment: The *man commands are just queueing a request that the action be taken and  reporting that the admin server got the request.  I know that you say you don't want to but you need to add a loop  and a status check in order to be sure that it is ok to proceed.

Comment: Thank you Tom. Yes, I'm quickly realizing that I will have to add a timed status loop to check that the database is properly shutdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some timeouts that can come into play:

> When an unconditional batch shutdown runs (PROSHUT -by), the following sequence of events takes place:
>
> If there are any running processes left after:
>
> - 30 Seconds - wake up clients waiting for locks.
> - 60 Seconds - wake up clients waiting for locks.
> - 90 Seconds - wake up clients waiting on screen input.
> - 5 Minutes - Resend the shutdown signal to remaining clients.
> - 10 Minutes - Send a terminate (SIGTERM) signal to remaining clients.

More info here:
http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P3222

You can tail the database.lg file and look for the messages telling you that the database is shut down:

```
[2017/02/06@20:20:56.353+0100] P-14292      T-13420 I SHUT    5: (542)   Server shutdown started by Jens on CON:.
[2017/02/06@20:20:56.499+0100] P-10276      T-11404 I BROKER  0: (15193) The normal shutdown of the database will continue for 10 Min 0 Sec if required.
[2017/02/06@20:20:56.499+0100] P-10276      T-11404 I BROKER  0: (2248)  Begin normal shutdown
[2017/02/06@20:20:57.499+0100] P-10276      T-11404 I BROKER  0: (2263)  Resending shutdown request to 0 user(s).
[2017/02/06@20:21:01.692+0100] P-10276      T-11404 I BROKER  0: (15109) At Database close the number of live transactions is 0.
[2017/02/06@20:21:01.692+0100] P-10276      T-11404 I BROKER  0: (15743) Before Image Log Completion at Block 1 Offset 5300.
[2017/02/06@20:21:01.693+0100] P-10276      T-11404 I BROKER  0: (453)   Logout by Jens on CON:.
[2017/02/06@20:21:01.694+0100] P-10276      T-11404 I BROKER   : (16869) Removed shared memory with segment_id: 50528256
[2017/02/06@20:21:01.694+0100] P-10276      T-11404 I BROKER   : (334)   Multi-user session end.
[2017/02/06@20:21:02.356+0100] P-14292      T-13420 I SHUT    5: (453)   Logout by Jens on CON:.
```

The (334) message is basically telling you that the database is shut down.

Another option could be to check for the database lock file (database.lk). It's only there if the database is running:

```
...
2017-02-06  20:21         2 228 224 mySportsDb.b1
2017-02-06  20:21         1 703 936 mySportsDb.d1
2017-02-06  20:21            32 768 mySportsDb.db
2017-02-06  20:21            89 643 mySportsDb.lg
2017-02-06  18:00               920 mySportsDb.lic
2017-02-06  20:26               265 mySportsDb.lk
...
```

There are also a couple of scripts you can run to check the status of the database. See more here:

http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P136887

Comment: Thank you @Jensd ! Do you know if there is a timeout period for the database shutdown and how long it is? For instance, if my only option is to trail the log file or sleep-retry searching for the lock file, what should be my max length of time to trail/search?

Comment: @PrestonM Some default timouts are present. I've added a link to those in the answer. If you just are throwing away these databases perhaps you can just force a shutdown (proshut -F or proshut -byF) - but that will destroy them...

Comment: that is a great suggestion. These are test servers, so actually I will be throwing away these databases.